Strapi v5.5.0 Media Library Crop Option Not Working in Production Mode
I'm using Strapi v5.5.0, and I've encountered an issue with the Media Library's image crop feature.
In the development environment, the crop option works perfectly, but in the production mode on my live site, the crop option doesn't load, and the Crop Library UI seems to break.

Here’s what I’ve checked so far:
The production build was created using npm run build and started with npm run start.
There are no apparent errors in the browser console or server logs.
The permissions for the /public/uploads folder are correctly set, and images upload without issues.
All other Media Library functionalities are working fine.
It seems like this issue might be related to environment-specific settings or the production build configuration.
Questions:
What could be causing this discrepancy between the dev and production environments?
Are there specific build or environment configurations for Strapi that I might be missing?
How can I debug or fix this issue to make the crop feature work in production?
Any insights or suggestions are greatly appreciated.
Environment Details:
Strapi Version: 5.5.0
Node.js Version: 20.18.1
Database: MySQL
Deployment Platform: Plesk
Thank you!

I have this issue myself. Specifically it seems the cropping is broken when using an Amazon S3 bucket (which I also had CORS issues with). In dev this isn't an issue my dev is setup to use the local file system. I have found mounting an EFS in place of using S3 also solves the issue.
To further help debug, where are you storing your images on development and production?
Do they differ?
